# What are these GC Minor Nursery Full log messages in my Blazor WebAssembly app trying to tell me?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a Blazor WebAssembly app.  I have recently started seeing the following log messages show up in my browser's (Chrome) dev console:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 0.94ms, stw 0.94ms promoted 29K major size: 2592K in use: 1873K los size: 1024K in use: 183K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 0.58ms, stw 0.60ms promoted 37K major size: 2624K in use: 1915K los size: 1024K in use: 183K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 1.00ms, stw 1.02ms promoted 23K major size: 2720K in use: 2009K los size: 1024K in use: 183K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 0.63ms, stw 0.63ms promoted 18K major size: 2816K in use: 2127K los size: 1024K in use: 183K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 0.87ms, stw 0.88ms promoted 11K major size: 2944K in use: 2254K los size: 1024K in use: 183K
```

The values next to `major size` and the first `in use` tag steadily increase increase until major size reaches roughly 19000K and the following messages display:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 0.82ms, stw 0.84ms promoted 18K major size: 19408K in use: 18141K los size: 1024K in use: 48K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 4192K in use: 18333K
blazor.webassembly.js:1 L: GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 34.43ms, stw 36.44ms los size: 1024K in use: 32K
```

Then the whole cycle repeats itself.

I understand these messages are related to garbage collection, but what are they specifically trying to communicate and could they indicate that I have a potential memory leak in my client?